# How to Send Email with Input + Button + JS Script and Mailchimp

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, mailchimp

I have this html code:

```
    <div class="oana" data-wow-delay="500ms">
         <div class="bg-overlay bg-pink opacity-7"></div>
              <form class="search-box position-relative bg-change">
                        <h5 class="color-white font-weight-600 text-capitalize mb-3">Newsletter</h5>
                        <p class="color-white newsletter-para mb-4"> Vestibulum auctor nunc vitae diam eleifend, in maximus metus sollicitudin. Quisque vitae sodales lectus. </p>
                        <div class="input-group">
                           
       <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email..." required>
       <button type="submit" class="search-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope line-height-35px"></i> </button>
    
       </div>
            </form>
    </div>
```

also, I have this custom website code from Mailchimp>

```
<script id="mcjs">!function(c,h,i,m,p){m=c.createElement(h),p=c.getElementsByTagName(h)[0],m.async=1,m.src=i,p.parentNode.insertBefore(m,p)}(document,"script","https://chimpstatic.com/mcjs-connected/js/users/db2de4cdb7f3405b9fa0d298f/a3d9fbac0ac1eb37d0633a6d0.js");</script>
```

Can anyone tell me how can I integrate this JS script in the form, so that the email works very well. Because I put this script before  I check the connection, and it is ok, but the newsletter still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need that JS script anymore, it is just for the connection you made on the setup mailchimp after SignUp. You must follows this 2 simple steps:

**Step One:** Login on mailchimp.com and go to section **Signup Forms -> Embedded forms**

See this image for example:

[image]

**STEP TWO**. By default, you can copy that mailchimp code anywhere you want on the html page.

**But if you have already a form**, like I already have one, you must remember/follow those 4 lines from mailchimp code:  **<form action=** , **<input type=**, **<button type=** and **<script type=**

All you need is too copy **<form action=**, **name** and **ID** from mailchimp form and paste it on your form. Also, copy all **<script type=** line

In my case, this is how the code (from the beginning) looks like after update. Mention that the **<script type=** line you can copy and paste it before `</head>` tag. But I leave it as it is, in the form tag.

```
  <div class="oana" data-wow-delay="500ms">
            <div class="bg-overlay bg-pink opacity-7"></div>
             <form action="https://neculaifantanaru.us1.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=db2de4cdb7f3405b9fa0d298f&amp;id=e55f160948" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="search-box position-relative bg-change" target="_blank" novalidate>
                <h5 class="color-white font-weight-600 text-capitalize mb-3">Newsletter</h5>
                <p class="color-white newsletter-para mb-4"> Vestibulum auctor nunc vitae diam eleifend, in maximus metus sollicitudin. Quisque vitae sodales lectus. My website is https://neculaifantanaru.com </p>
                <div class="input-group">

      <input type="email" name="EMAIL" id="mce-EMAIL" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email..." required>
      <button type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="search-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope line-height-35px"></i> </button>

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/mc-validate.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'>(function($) {window.fnames = new Array(); window.ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';}(jQuery));var $mcj = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
    </div>
```

**Note:** If you leave the  `<script type=..</script>` line code on the subscription form, like I did in the code above, people will be able to register but will not receive any confirmation. But if you copy it before `</head>` tag, people will be redirect to a new window confirmation page.

More information about installing here: https://mailchimp.com/help/host-your-own-signup-forms/